# Next.js13 - Generate dynamic routes from multiple data sources

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm currently building an e-commerce site. In my backend I have an entity `product` that is related to `collection` & `categories`. On my product-page, I want to display filtering on all available `collections` & `categories`. I want the path to be `/products/{category-slug || collection-slug}`.

Currently I have this folder structure(App router):

```
products /
  [slug] /
    layout.tsx
    (collections) /
      page.tsx
    (categories) /
      page.tsx
```

But this generates error saying that page not found. That is due to the following line of code in `(categories)/page.tsx`:

```
const category = await getCategoryProducts(params.slug);
if (!category) {
    notFound();
}
```

&
`(collections)/page.tsx`:

```
const collection = await getCollectionProducts(params.slug);
if (!collection) {
    notFound();
}
```

I have also looked into the option of having one page.tsx and make two requests to the database in `generateStaticParams()`. This however is not a viable solution.

If I remove `notFound()` I get other errors saying it cant read attributes, since both page.tsx files are being triggered for a single path.

What can I do?